# Fake a multi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, bash, multidimensional-array

As bash does not support multi-dimensional arrays, how can I fake it so I could access it like this:

```
#declare
array["foo"] = "bar"

#print
echo array["foo"] //how to display declared 'bar' here?
```

So the question is: what I need to do, to print out the `bar` when accessing `array["foo"]`?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html#TWODIM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use [associative arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays):

```
declare -A array=()

#declare
array["foo"]="bar"

#print
echo "${array["foo"]}"
```

And you can fake multi-dimensional arrays with it like

```
i=1
j=2
array[$i,$j]=1234
echo "${array[$i,$j]}"
```

Comment: It only works for one element: `declare -a array=(["moo"]="cow" ["john"]="doe")` : `echo "${array["moo"]}" //returns doe[!] which is wrong`, `echo "${array["john"]}" //returns doe aswell which is fine`

Comment: When I do only one echo like `echo ${array["moo"]}"` it works fine, but problem appears when I want to print more than one array element.

Comment: @Lucas Make sure you declare your array as associative with `declare -A` not `-a`.

Comment: Thats strange - I have used `-a` parameter because when I do `-A` this is what I get: `declare: -A: invalid option`
`declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]` I am using the following bash: `#!/usr/local/bin/bash`

Comment: I think that `declare -A` is in 4.0 and later versions of bash. I'm running the `3.2.48`.

Comment: @Lucas Yes it's only available in 4.0. The latest version of bash is 4.2 and I was expecting that most systems has already upgraded to 4.0 at least.

Comment: OVH's dedicated server running on latest FreeBSD has installed the default version of `3.2.48`. I'd better upgrade this oldie. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest going for 4.2.45. It seems the most stable over all its previous versions.